# How to work with multiple inputs fields with .map - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an assignment to make cryptocurrenty converter using API from coinmarketcap. I have manage to retrieve data and show everything but problem is that all fields act like one field.

You can see it here:
https://repl.it/repls/IncompatibleWhirlwindHarddrive

```
function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState("");
  const [coinValue, setCoinValue] = useState("")
  const [value, setValue] = useState("")

  useEffect(() => {
  let url = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://sandbox-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest"

    axios
      .get(url,{
        headers: {
          'X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY': 'c8643baa-31bf-4d31-8868-af73ce84766b'
        },
      })
      .then(result => setData(result.data.data));
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <table className="table ">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Short Name</th>
            <th>$ Value</th>
            <th>Last 24h</th>
            <th>Amount you own</th>
            <th>$ value of your coins</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

          {Array.isArray(data) &&
            data.map(objects => {
              let price = objects.quote.USD.price.toFixed(2)
              let Result = (function() {
                return price * coinValue
            });
              return (
                <tr key={objects.name}>
                  <td>{objects.name}</td>
                  <td>
                    {objects.symbol}
                  </td>
                  <td onLoad={()=>setValue(price)}>
                    {price}
                  </td>
                  <td style={{color: objects.quote.USD.percent_change_24h > 0 ? "green" : "red"}}>{objects.quote.USD.percent_change_24h.toFixed(2)}</td>
                  <td>
                    <input required type="number" onChange={e => setCoinValue(e.target.value)} /> <br/>
                    <button className="btn" disabled={!coinValue} type="submit" onClick={Result}>Submit</button>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <Result></Result>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              );
            })}
        </tbody>
      </table>
      </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I need to every button be disabled until there is some value in input field but on input field that goes with that button. 
Also I have to show conversion for only that field that input has value when you press submit.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you intend to give your API key out to everyone?

Comment: Its public API so I don`t have a problem :) Its only for assignment not for production but thanks for noticing. I need this to be done and not make people go register and get they own API. Its easier this way :)

Comment: You probably need separate state for each input. Then you can say something like disabled={!coinValue[objects.symbol]}

Comment: I thought I need to do something like that but to be honest I don`t know how.

Comment: Take a look at the handleInputChange part of this article: https://medium.com/@geeky_writer_/using-react-hooks-to-create-awesome-forms-6f846a4ce57